# how to prevent the openTip message box from disappearing when the mouse cursor leave the target html element

Tags: jquery, opentip

As described in the title, I need to keep the message tooltip created with opentip always showing. But by default, the message box will disappear when the mouse cursor leaves the HTML element that the message box attached to.

Please help modify the code below( or visit https://jsfiddle.net/671ptukx/ to edit the code directly) to achieve the effect as stated above.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
var myOpentip = new Opentip($("#targetTag"),"Need to prevent this tooltip message from disappearing when mouse leaves the \"Example Text\" area",{target:"#targetTag", tipJoint: "top" ,background:"wheat",showOn: 'creation'});
```

Comment: The tooltip functions on hovering the element.if you need to show it always you can avoid using tooltip right?

Comment: I find the opentip library just meets many needs of my project, it can achieve many fancy effects easily, I just need to solve this auto disappear issue as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myOpentip = new Opentip($("#targetTag"),"Need to prevent this tooltip message from disappearing when mouse leaves the \"Example Text\" area",{target:"#targetTag", tipJoint: "top" ,background:"wheat",showOn: 'creation',
 
    target: true,
    fixed: true,
    hideTrigger: "closeButton"});
```

Use this script or check the updated fiddle ,https://jsfiddle.net/Hema_Nandagopal/671ptukx/2/

Comment: Wow, even better than I expected! I didn't think about adding a close button. That is very convenient with that close button added. Thank you soooo much Hema!!

Comment: I'm glad that I helped.Welcome Yolo :)